# Ursina engine update() command

Tags: python, game-development, ursina

I'm having problems with my game on ursina.
I'm actually doing sprint, dash, double jump, wall run and wall climb
for now and I'm having problems with dash and sprint (I didn't actually do the rest for now) and the mechanics are changing or not working

```py
def update():
    if not held_keys["shift"] and held_keys["w"] and not player.air_time:
        dash = False
        player.speed = 15
    if held_keys["shift"] and held_keys["w"] and player.air_time:
        dash = True
        player.speed = 100
        player.gravity = 3
    if not player.air_time: 
        dash = False
        player.speed = 15

    if held_keys['control'] and held_keys['w']:
        sprint = True
        player.speed = 30
    if not held_keys['control']:
        sprint = False
        player.speed = 15
```

I tried to make two update() thingies, didn't work, dash() and sprint() and didn't work, update() and update2() and some other things

Answer (score 0):

You should do dash and sprint variables global.

```
def update():
   global daash,sprint
   [rest of the code]
```